# is there a way one completable feature notify other unknown(who is waiting for result from other feature) after its execution done?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

i have list of formulas(Around 1000) and am trying to executed in async way & in multithreaded env. And those formulas are dependent on other formulas result value, but there is no way to know which formula exactly dependent on which one.

is there anyway/approach in java 8's completable features to achieve this?

Comment: "but there is no way to know which formula exactly dependent on which one" isn't that kind of critical information?  In order to answer this question accurately there needs to be a little bit more detail on how that interdependency works since for any type of multi-threading, the interdependency is the hard part and without precise details on how these calculations need to interact it is difficult to give a solution.  However, generally Java 8's Completable features / CompletionStage could seemingly help you.

Comment: Can you give a code example? What you have so far?

Comment: Even without async execution, you have to know the dependencies, to be able to calculate prerequisites first.

Comment: Found solution to Problem. i implemented a custom Concurrent Map(**Thread Safe**), while getting a value from map using key,
**a thread wait until that value is available(maximum wait time is 5sec) in map**.

And executing all the formulas using `CompletableFuture` in Async Mode.
**keeping all evaluated formula answers in the custom map to make available for other Futures who are depending on other formula answers**.

Waiting for all formulas getting evaluated.

**_its working thanks for your response_**